# Parallelize program

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a program compound of several `.m` files. The program runs calling one of them (main) named `tests.m`, and from there I call another `optFun.m` where I compute different parameters. These parameters are computed inside a `while` loop which finish when there is no change of their values in a number of times (e.g. 4500).
The program works fine but I have to execute it like 200 times to get 200 different sets of values. Further I can use a computer with >12 cores so I have changed a little the main `.m` file including a `parfor` statement, to deploy 12 workers of matlab. My goal is to obtain 12 different solutions (executions of the initial program) in one round.

```
function [] = tests(Num)
matlabpool open local 12;  
y = zeros(itermax,15);  
z = zeros(itermax,9);
parfor i = 1:itermax   
    [iternum tTot SolOpt ImpCostMAX minABFmax ABFmax ImportCosteABS] =...
             optFun(N, K, AntNum,...  
                    q, eps, Rt, Rs, theta, maxiter,...
                    strcat(particad,num2str(i)));   
     y(i,:) = [ i; iternum; tTot; SolOpt; ImpCostMAX(1); ImpCostMAX(2);...
                q; eps; N; K; AntNum; maxiter;...
                SolOpt/ImpCostMAX(1); SolOpt/ImpCostMAX(2); SolOpt/N];  
     z(i,:) = [ i; minABFmax(1); minABFmax(2); minABFmax(3); ABFmax(1);...
                ABFmax(2); ABFmax(3);...
                ImportCosteABS(1); ImportCosteABS(2)];   
end %parfor

matlabpool close;  
dlmwrite(nombre, y, 'delimiter', ' ','precision', '%9.5f');  
dlmwrite(b, z, 'delimiter', ' ','precision', '%9.5f');
```

I have run the 12 workers of matlab but now **the program seems to stop before it reaches an optimal or correct results**. It seems like the parameters solution of my program are outputted before reaching the 4500 iterations of the while loop.
Although I obtain 12 different solutions It seems like the 12 workers where sharing the values of some of the variables so they stop when other workers improve solutions enough or the sum of several of them is considered a correct solution.
Could you help me to understand what is happening?

Thank you very much in advance
Regards

Comment: You might want to provide a code example instead of describing the code

Comment: Can you make sure that unexpected behaviour actually happens? So take one of those input/output combinations and run it separately to see that it is really different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already run it separately and I realized that something was wrong. I can make a test using a normal for loop. The program take a time to obtain solution. Thanks regards.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem in the past. Are you sure that the "independent" evaluations of your for loop do not exchange information regarding the convergence of your solution via a common variable they all use? Say, you define a `convergence=zeros(1);` outside the `parfor` and then have all subsequent calls of optFun.m use the same variable. This might also apply to the function storing intermediate values inside an array.

While I can't say if this is indeed your problem (no code sample) it might just be. In which case I'd recommend creating an independent container for each of the evaluations (e.g. a `zeros(NoEvals,NoThingsToStore)` matrix where they would keep the data independently of each other).

Comment: Hi Artur,I suspect you are right. I don't see now what is the shared variable, but I will make some tests. Funtion 'tests.m' only sets some parameters and calls optFun.m. and the values they return are save it in z() and y() arrays, each worker in a row.